# Why do I see nothing when I try to inspect a cell in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: html, google-sheets, reverse-engineering

I'm playing around with writing a spreadsheet app, mostly to get an understanding of the technological options and challenges.

I've quickly discovered that making a grid component able to display thousands or rows / columns is a very complicated task.

I wanted to get some inspiration from the Google Spreadsheet app, but whenever I inspect the document it seems all data disappears (is it quantum physics?).

Take for instance this [simple grid](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OnferPeF6nfZkyXNCKrEDrHH8deQZu40thKX6tKbvSI/edit#gid=0). If I do CTRL + SHIFT + Right-Click on the HELLO Cell I can inspect but the "goog-inline-block grid4-inner-container" div seems to be the deeper I can go. Every element inside seems empty (I've tried unrolling quite a few of the "scrollable_right_" things).
[image: dom inspector for a simple spreadsheet]

Also disturbing is what happens if I search (CTRL+F) for hello in the "Elements" view of the inspector:
[image: looking for HELLO in the Elements view]

It is only found in what looks like the data used to bootstrap the app, but nowhere in the DOM.

How is this even possible? Can things be displayed and not be in the DOM?
How can I find out which document node actually contains the "HELLO" text here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the cells are drawn in a canvas!

To see it, type this in the JS console: `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL()` and click on the URL.